# How correctly use Gson to deserialize an object of generic type through a static utility method?

Tags: java, generics, gson, deserialization

I've seen a number of other similar looking questions, but I think there's a level of abstraction on top of those that makes the difference. Namely, I have a utility class with a static generic wrapper method to deserialize an object of generic type (unknown at build time):

```
public final class Utils {

    public static final Gson sGson = new Gson();

    public static synchronized <T> T fromJson(String doc) {
        return sGson.fromJson(doc, new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

A simple class to test it on:

```
public class TestDocument {
    public TestDocument(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String test;
}
```

This works well:

```
assertEquals(
   new TestDocument("test").test, 
   ((TestDocument) Utils.sGson.fromJson(
                      "{\"test\": \"test\"}", 
                      new TypeToken<TestDocument>(){}.getType())).test);
```

But what looks like an equivalent way to call this though the static generic utility method does not:

```
assertEquals(
   new TestDocument("test").test, 
   Utils.<TestDocument>fromJson("{\"test\": \"test\"}").test);
```

Throws the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
>   cannot be cast to TestDocument

Is there a way to make it work through the generic method?

Answer (score 1):

If it would be possible, `Gson` probably would add already this method and it could look like this:

```
TestDocument document = gson.<TestDocument>fromJson(json);
```

Method with this signature:

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException
```

has included `JavaDoc`:

> This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the
>   specified class. It is not suitable to use if the specified class is a
>   generic type since it will not have the generic type information
>   because of the **Type Erasure feature of Java**. Therefore, this method
>   should not be used if the desired type is a generic type. Note that
>   this method works fine if the any of the fields of the specified
>   object are generics, just the object itself should not be a generic
>   type. For the cases when the object is of generic type, invoke
>   `fromJson(String, Type)`. If you have the Json in a `Reader` instead of a `String`, use `fromJson(Reader, Class)` instead.

Even second parameter name is `classOfT` has meaning `the class of T`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few type usage hints:

- Using `<T>` without passing an actual type is a hoax due to the generic types erasure.
- Passing the type as `Class<T>` is not a very good idea because `###.class` merely represents a class loaded by JVM (except the primitive types). Having that, `Class<List<String>>` and `Class<List<Map<Integer, ?>>>` are totally the same `List.class` losing type parameterization therefore making Gson (de)serialize work without proper types in mind (LinkedHashTreeMap, for example, is a good example if I remember).
- Gson mostly works with `Type` that is a super type interface for any type that can be represented by the Java type system (including classes, `ParameterizedType`, etc). See https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-
- `TypeToken` is a good example of a generic type holder in Java, including it produces proper type information depending on how it was build. It can be used to make your method type safe: `public static <T> T fromJson(String doc, TypeToken<? extends T> typeToken) { return sGson.fromJson(doc, typeToken.getType()); }`. Type tokens can be cached into public (yes) static final fields holding real parameterization due being immutable and thread-safe across threads.

Bonus:

- No `synchronized` is necessary there: `Gson` instances are thread-safe too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is impossible to do this in Java without passing the actual type explicitly so that it is known at build time.

Here's one solution:

```
    public static synchronized <T> T fromJson(String doc, Class<T> type) {
        return sGson.fromJson(doc, type);
    }
```

Then the test passes:

```
    assertEquals((new TestDocument("test").test), Utils.<TestDocument>fromJson("{\"test\": \"test\"}", TestDocument.class).test);
```

This looks like it can be done in a much simpler and more elegant way in this particular (intentionally oversimplified) example, but may be the only option when it's a part of a larger, more complex scenario.